# Python two Tkinter Widgets on the exact same position

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, grid

Is there a way to place two frames on the exact same position? But only one is visible.

I tried it like this:

```
def open_one(event):
    Frame2.grid_forget()       
    Frame1.grid(column=1,row=2,rowspan=3,sticky=W, padx = 50)
def open_two(event):
    Frame1.grid_forget()
    Frame2.grid(column=1,row=2,rowspan=3,sticky=W, padx = 50)
```

But the Grid manager reserves spaces in the grid for both next to each other an all my other widgets are on wrong positions now.

Comment: This is easy with the `pack` manager, but as you said it does not work with the `grid` manager. The only hack that I can imagine it to create an additional invisible cell at the end of the grid (with a null size) and temporarily put the unwanted frame into that invisible cell

Comment: @sciroccorics: actually, it's harder with `pack` than with `grid` and `place`.

Comment: _"the Grid manager reserves spaces in the grid for both next to each other"_ - that is a false statement. If you remove one frame and put in another with the exact same parameters, it will use the exact same space. However, if one frame is larger than the other it may cause the widget to resize, but `grid` doesn't reserve space for both.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. The code you posted will not cause tkinter to reserve space for both widgets.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grid_forget` as demonstrated below, to remove a `tk.Frame` and replace it with another:

```
import tkinter as tk


class Display(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, color):
        super().__init__(parent, bg=color, width=100, height=100)
        tk.Label(self, text=color).pack(padx=50, pady=50)


class App(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.displays = [Display(self, 'cyan'), Display(self, 'green')]
        self.showing_counter = 0
        self.displays[self.showing_counter].grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.swap_frames_btn = tk.Button(self, text='swap', command=self.swap_displays)
        self.swap_frames_btn.grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.mainloop()

    def swap_displays(self):
        """replace a frame with another"""
        self.displays[self.showing_counter].grid_forget()
        self.showing_counter = (self.showing_counter + 1) % 2
        self.displays[self.showing_counter].grid(row=0, column=0)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    App()
```

Comment: _"You probably cannot place two objects at the same location"_ - that is false, You can put two objects at the same time in at least a couple different ways -- one with `place` and one with `grid`.